# JMapPane doesn't update after adding new layer

Tags: geotools

After adding a new layer it doesn't show inside JMapPane, is there a way to force this?
I already tried using MapLayerEvent

```
styleSld = Stil.createFromSLD(inputStream);
layer = new FeatureLayer(pointCollection, styleSld);
layer.setTitle("G_POINT");

getMapPane().getMapContent().addLayer(layer);
MapLayerEvent mple = new MapLayerEvent(layer, MapLayerEvent.DATA_CHANGED);
MapLayerListEvent mplle = new MapLayerListEvent(getMapPane().getMapContent(), layer,
    getMapPane().getMapContent().layers().indexOf(layer), mple);
getMapPane().layerChanged(mplle);
```

The same code is used for refreshing content when drawing new feature and it works normaly.

I also tried running new ResetAction and nothing happens. If I interacted with a map by (zoom change or by clicking ResetButton or Drag) it will render the layer.

EDIT

The problem is caused by,

```
getMapPane().getMapContent().getViewport().setBounds(new ReferencedEnvelope(-100, 100, -100, 100,
                getMapPane().getMapContent().getCoordinateReferenceSystem()));
```

after I remove this it works nicely, but then need to go through the code and manually create bounds if a return is null, but it will be much easier with this part in the code.

Comment: is -100, 100, -100, 100 a valid bounding box in your coordinate system? I would use the bounds of my layer

Comment: The coordinate system is not set yet, there is a possibility to open a WMS in WGS84, GK6 or some other coordinate system, the same is with other details. When loading a WMS without any bounds set in MapContent it returns  
2017-08-05T11:34:25.234+0200  SEVERE  The scale denominator must be positive.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scale denominator must be positive.  

Solved this by adding  
getMapPane().getMapContent().getViewport().setBounds(wmsLayer.getBounds())

Comment: This should propbably be a new question but given a layer l from a WMS use the following          ReferencedEnvelope envelope2 = new ReferencedEnvelope(l.getEnvelope(crs));

          System.out.println(crs.getName() + " [ " + envelope2.getMinX() + "," + envelope2.getMinY() + ","
              + envelope2.getMaxX() + "," + envelope2.getMaxY() + " ]");

Answer (score 1):

Without more of your code it is hard to tell what is happening.

But you shouldn't need to send your own event. If you look in [MapContent](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/34d7eaec9aa89f37032522ff1a63e2f61352b423/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/map/MapContent.java) you will see the [`addIfAbsent` method](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/34d7eaec9aa89f37032522ff1a63e2f61352b423/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/map/MapContent.java#L1056):

```
    @Override
    public boolean addIfAbsent(Layer element) {
        boolean added = super.addIfAbsent(element);
        if (added) {
            if (layerListener != null) {
                element.addMapLayerListener(layerListener);
            }
            checkViewportCRS();
            fireLayerAdded(element, size() - 1, size() - 1);
        }
        return added;
    }
```

I would put a breakpoint in there and see if it is firing the event to the listeners. This should end up calling [`layerAdded`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/34d7eaec9aa89f37032522ff1a63e2f61352b423/modules/unsupported/swing/src/main/java/org/geotools/swing/AbstractMapPane.java#L785) in AbstractMapPane. This method should set the full extent and force a redraw.

If everything is working to there then the last place to look is in [`JMapPane.drawLayers()`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/34d7eaec9aa89f37032522ff1a63e2f61352b423/modules/unsupported/swing/src/main/java/org/geotools/swing/JMapPane.java#L178) which is called with `false` for `createNewImage` and thus only clears the part of the map in view before it forces a redraw of all the layers at line 204. So I would put a final breakpoint there and check your new layer is in the `mapContent.layers()`.

Comment: I edited my question.